# TFS 2015: Permissions for Source Control Explorer

Tags: team-foundation-server

I am currently facing the following situtation:

We have a TFS 2015 and I want to set up a user, for developers to work in Visual Studio 2015 with the Source Control Explorer.

I have set the following permissions on TFS Server level:
"View instance-level information"

Also I have added the user to the Project Collection Administrators group.

Unfortunately the user still only see's an empty window in Source Control Explorer and is not able to see any team projects in the collection.

Does anyone have a hint what I'm missing?

---

All users are affected that are not Part of the group "Team Foundation Server Administrators".

Comment: Is this affecting just a single user, or a whole bunch?

Comment: Please use the edit functionality to add information to your question. The answer field is for answers.